# Squaring values of dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I am using Python 2.7, still learning about dictionaries. I am focusing on performing numerical computations for dictionaries and need some help.

I have a dictionary and I would like to square the values in it:

```
 dict1 = {'dog': {'shepherd': 5,'collie': 15,'poodle': 3,'terrier': 20},
'cat': {'siamese': 3,'persian': 2,'dsh': 16,'dls': 16},
'bird': {'budgie': 20,'finch': 35,'cockatoo': 1,'parrot': 2}
```

I want:

```
 dict1 = {'dog': {'shepherd': 25,'collie': 225,'poodle': 9,'terrier': 400},
'cat': {'siamese': 9,'persian': 4,'dsh': 256,'dls': 256},
'bird': {'budgie': 400,'finch': 1225,'cockatoo': 1,'parrot': 4}
```

I tried:

```
 dict1_squared = dict**2.

 dict1_squared = pow(dict,2.)

 dict1_squared = {key: pow(value,2.) for key, value in dict1.items()}
```

I did not have any success with my attempts.

Comment: You have to iterate through the loop (2 levels deep). Then you need to times itself by itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were very close with the dictionary comprehension.  The issue is that *value* in your solution is a dictionary itself, so you have to iterate over it too.

```
dict1_squared = {key: {k: pow(v,2) for k,v in value.items()} for key, value in dict1.items()}
```

Answer (score 4):

It's because you have nested dictionaries, look:

```
results = {}

for key, data_dict in dict1.iteritems():
    results[key] = {key: pow(value,2.) for key, value in data_dict.iteritems()}
```

Answer (score 4):

One of those cases where I might prefer loops:

```
for d in dict1.values():
    for k in d:
        d[k] **= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I think it would be a good idea to work through a tutorial. [Here is one from tutorialspoint](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/index.htm). You said you are trying to square the dictionary, but that is not what you are trying to do. You are trying to square the values within a dictionary. To square the values within the dictionary, you first need to get the values. Python's `for` loops can help with this.

```
# just an example
test_dict = {'a': {'aa': 2}, 'b': {'bb': 4}}

# go through every key in the outer dictionary
for key1 in test_dict:

    # set a variable equal to the inner dictionary
    nested_dict = test_dict[key1]

    # get the values you want to square
    for key2 in nested_dict:

        # square the values
        nested_dict[key2] = nested_dict[key2] ** 2
```

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is alway the same you can do this way:

```
for k,w in dict1.items():
    for k1,w1 in w.items():
        print w1, pow(w1,2)

20 400
1 1
2 4
35 1225
5 25
15 225
20 400
3 9
3 9
16 256
2 4
16 256
```

Answer (score 0):

## Dictionary comprehension example with key any square of value:

```
square = {i:i**2 for i in range(1,8)}
print(square)

            #-- or --#

square2 = {f"Square of {i} is":i**2  for i in range(1,8)}
for k,v in square2.items():
  print(f"{k}:{v}")
```